# MongoDb Fast Queries Javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am reading that document: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24mod

```
$mod
```

The $mod operator allows you to do fast modulo queries to replace a common case for where clauses. For example, the following $where query:

```
db.things.find( "this.a % 10 == 1")
```

can be replaced by:

```
db.things.find( { a : { $mod : [ 10 , 1 ] } } )
```

So I didn't understand what `fast` means here. Performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not benchmarked this, but it will probably indeed mean performance. Apparently the "$where" executes javascript for each object, but "$mod" is a mongodb native operator, which should be much faster, because there is no need to execute any javascript for each object. Have also a look at the following sentence from the documentation:

```
Javascript executes more slowly than the native operators listed on this page, 
but is very flexible.
```

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-JavascriptExpressionsand%7B%7B%24where%7D%7D

Comment: Do you have any idea about @Andrew Orsich's index answer?

Comment: For javascript queries it's not possible to use indexes, because the javascript has to be evaluated for each object, which is selected with your query. So: if you have the choice between a built-in operator like *$mod* and a javascript, the javascript should always be slower, because the javascript is evaluated for each object *and*  it can not use an index, while the builtin operator is evaluated only ones when your query is parsed by mongodb *and* it can use an index. It would probably be interesting, to benchmark this ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just one more. What you mean with indexing can I read it from anywhere? I think I don't know what.

Answer (score 1):

Any javascript/regex queries in mongodb can't use indexes and work slow. So answer on your question is yes, documentation say about performance.

More info about server side javascript you can find [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Server-side+Code+Execution)